# STM32 code size: iostream vs sdtio

Tags: stm32

i have STM32F4 with 512kb flash. i have 2 project: c++ with iostream and c with printf ( in both i have override __io_putchar to USART ). Code woth iostram has ~400kb, code with printf has 10kb. Is it normal? is any way to more optimalize cout ?

Thank you for help : )

Comment: The best way is to do not use it.

Comment: The best way is to write own "stdio" which will very lightweight and fulfill requirements of your project.

Comment: Ok, so thank You for help : )